# Pointer Size in a C++ program

Tags: c++, pointers, architecture

I know pointer size is dependent on architecture of the system, but when virtual memory is considered and say it is greater than physical memory, then how a variable pointer size is limited by architecture?

Comment: within one single program, virtual memory is limited to pointer size.

It's however perfectly possible for every instance of multiple processes on a single machine to use the whole virtual address space on its own, so you are able to use a lot more memory than pointer size is able to address.

Comment: @mfro So on a system of 32 bit physical memory and 32 bit CPU, can't there be virtual memory of more than 32 bits?

Comment: Yes, it can, but not for one single process (as it can only access memory/peripherials behind 32 bit wide addresses). With an MMU implementing an address space id, this can be seen as bit extension to the 32 bit address (used to switch between different 32 bit wide address spaces for different processes).

Comment: Can you please the answer as a solution if you're happy with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the size of a pointer?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6751749/90527)

Answer (score 2):

A pointer must be able to hold the address of any location in memory.
As a result, a 32 bit system (usually) needs a 32 bit pointer!

Note the "usually" here, as member function pointers can be completely different in size and there are many other exceptions to this rule of thumb. If in doubt, or it matters a lot, write a quick program to check on the architecture you're targeting.